# Why is Enter key on Input box triggering Button click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, browser, knockout.js

I am confused. The website is based on asp.net (aspx), knockout 2.2.1, jquery 1.9.1 and I wanted to make Enter key on input box to act as a button click on several pages. So I thought I need to use something like [enterKey](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc) ko custom binding but I found, on some pages where pages were wrapped with 'form' by master page, enter key was already calling button click handler!

myPage html:

```
<form method="post" action="myPage.aspx" id="form1">

    <input type="text" data-bind="valueFiltered: amountInDollar"/>
    <button data-bind="click: save, enable: canSave">Save</button>

</form>
```

I am handling keypress event to allow only numeric keys and enter key (by returning true) and javascript looks like:

```
my.save = function () { // enter key calling this function!!??
    var amount = parseInt(my.amountInDollar(), 10);
    post(amount.toString()); // ajax call
};
```

On pages that was not wrapped by 'form', I had to use enterKey binding to make enter key to work.

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: That's the default behavior of buttons in a form. The first button after the input will be "clicked" when you press enter in the input.

Comment: @KevinB - I do not think that is entirely accurate. Try pushing enter inside of this input. It will "click" the next submit input. http://jsfiddle.net/VfeyY/1

Comment: A `<button>` element without a type is by default a submit button, and pressing enter in a text input will submit the form, even without a submit button, it's the default behavior

Comment: @TravisJ Yup, next "Submit" button. if there's only one button without a defined type, it's a submit.

Comment: @KevinB - Interestingly, it seems that it just directly calls the onsubmit function of the parent form. I removed the input type=submit from the fiddle and it still hit the submit function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VfeyY/4/

Comment: Thanks all, something new I didn't know. So can I depend on this default behavior without worrying about any cross-browser issue?

Comment: Yes, pressing enter in a text input inside a form will always submit the form.